# How can i call startActivity() to use ACTION_SEND from a different class

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to build an Android plugin to extend the ACTION_SEND functionality, but when i'm trying to call the activity to share a plain text using:

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, title));
```

i get this error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

The thing is, that in my last line of code i have FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK implemented.
Here is my code:

```
public class ShareMenu{
private Context context;


public ShareMenu(Context context){
    this.context = context;

}

public static void buildHomeShareMenu(Context context) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mtitle);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, mtitle));

}
```

I've tried to call just startActivity passing the instance mIntent, and works, but even i've noted if you just do these you can call other activities, but i can't figure it out how can i can pass the static Intent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MisterSquonk what can i call instead? i've tried mIntent.addFlags(mIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and i get this warning "The static field Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK should be accessed in a static way" and got the same error in runtime execution :).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

likely you are calling this code from a service this is a warning that you are creting a new task (series of activities - ie using back will just go back to launcher or the previous task)

the intent returned from createChooser doesnt have the flag set, so you should try to do:

```
Intent i = createChooser(mIntent, mtitle);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

i think it should work but I haven't tested it...